# Why can't I just compare the hashCode of two objects in order to find out if they are equal or not?

Tags: java, hash, equals, hashcode

Why do the equals methods implemented by Eclipse compare each value, wouldn't it be simpler to just compare the hashCodes of both objects?

From what I know:

- hashCode always generates the same hash for the same input
- So if two objects are equal, they should have the same hash
- If objects that are equal have the same hash, I can just check the hash in order to determine of objects are equal or not

edit: Related question, why does one always implement the hashCode when equals is implemented, if the hashCode isn't actually needed for equals?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> hashCode always generates the same hash for the same input

Correct.

> So if two objects are equal, they should have the same hash

Correct.

> If objects that are equal have the same hash, I can just check the hash in order to determine of objects are equal or not

*Non sequitur.* Objects that are unequal can also have the same hashcode. That is the purpose of a hashcode.

> Related question, why does one always implement the hashCode when equals is implemented, if the hashCode isn't actually needed for equals?

Because it is needed for hashing, in `HashMap, HashSet,` and friends. If you think your object will never be so used, don't override it, and good luck with that.

Comment: It should also be noted that the hash code must be the same 'during an execution of a Java application' (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode). So it might not be the same on different JVM instances.

Answer (score 2):

To complement [@EJP's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29714490/1093528), here is a perfectly valid, although useless, implementation of `.hashCode()`:

```
@Override
public int hashCode()
{
    return 42; // The Answer
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting this in very simple terms: while every squirrel is an animal, not every animal is a squirrel. The hashCode is usually used for quick lookup - it should be efficient and it should distribute data uniformly across a lookup table - see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function). But a hash function can generate collisions, which is why it shouldn't be used as a means of verifying object equality.

It's all very much dependent on the implementation of hashCode - as you can also see in fge's answer.

As to why it usually needs to be reimplemented when you override equals: they are both used when storing and retrieving objects from collections (for example a HashMap). The hashCode determines the place in the map where the object will be inserted, while equals is used to identify the object inside a collision bucket.